# Where is Hive in HDInsight

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

I'm logged into the HDInsight remote desktop machine and I'm on the Hadoop Console. But when I type Hive I get command not recognized although it works on my developer preview. Have I not configured my HDinsight cluster correctly. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Hadoop command prompt, type the following command:

cd %hive_home%\bin

It is recommended to submit hive job using Windows Azure PowerShell or HDInsight .NET SDK.  For more information, see http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/hdinsight/submit-hadoop-jobs-programmatically/.